# Big Cartel CSS Content Too Long

Tags: html, css, bigcartel

I'm working on a Big Cartel site and am currently customising one of the themes in both CSS and HTML. However, I have reached the stage where when I am adding more code to the theme.css and I go to click Done and it won't save as it says 'Content Too Long'. I still have a lot more code to add as I have 3 extra custom pages that will include a gallery and an additional form.

I'm not using Dugout and I don't want to use sprockets as I don't see how it will make the page shorter and comply with Big Cartel's character limit on the theme.css.

Has any one else had this issue? I wasn't aware there was ever a character limit on a CSS document, I assume this is Big Cartel who have enforced this. Is there any way round it?

The only solution I have so far is hosting an additional CSS file on my own server and calling it in the Layout HTML page.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unfortunately BigCartel has a character limit on CSS. [Here](https://twitter.com/ethcsclothing/status/461440001406808065)'s a Tweet from them.

It states,

> "The character limit is capped at 2^16 characters, but you can import
>   an externally hosted stylesheet if more space is needed."

You could try tweeting them directly if you still have questions: https://twitter.com/bigcartel